# How to add image object in the table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Note: Image is in the database named as "profileImage" I want to make image object that is dynamic as like other objects, whenever I add this code

```
{
   label: "Image",
   name: "profileImage",
}
```

it simply display the image endpoint like `3704545668418.PNG`
and the url for profileImage is `https://cloudclinicdevapi.azurewebsites.net/Profile/3704545668418.PNG`

Now please tell me how can I add image column in this table

```
this.state = {
  columns: [
    {
      label: "National ID",
      name: "nationalID",
      sortable: true,

      filter: true,

      options: {
        customBodyRender: (val) => (
          <NavLink className="NavLink" to={`/EditPatient?Patient=${val}`}>
            {val}
          </NavLink>
        ),
      },
    },
    {
      label: "Patient Name",
      name: "name",
      filter: true,
    },
    {
      //want to add Image here
    },
    {
      label: "Phone Number",
      name: "phone",
      sortable: true,
      filter: true,
    },
    {
      label: "Address",
      name: "address",
      sortable: true,

      filter: true,
    },
    {
      label: "ID",
      hide: true,
      name: "nationalID",
      button: {
        show: true,
        value: "Make an Appointments",
        operation: (val) => this.needAppointment(val),
      },
    },
  ],
  rowSelection: "single",
  rowData: [],
}`
```

Comment: Are you using some kind of table library?

Comment: yes, i am using materialUI table

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using [mui-datatables](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables). If so, you should be able to just use another custom renderer:

```js
{
  // add Image
  label: "Image",
  name: "profileImage",
  sortable: false,  
  filter: false,  
  options: {
    customBodyRender: (val) => (
      <img src={`https://cloudclinicdevapi.azurewebsites.net/Profile/${val}`} />
    ),
  },  
},
```

Comment: It is again displaying the image value like i mentioned in the question "3704545668418.PNG", but i want image there